# Print months between -6 and +6 months

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo months from 1 year range, like example date 02-2016

I want months between `(02-2016 - 6months)` and `(02-2016 + 6 months)`

```
$now = strtotime(date('d-m-Y'));
$start = strtotime('-6 months');
$end = strtotime('+6 months');

while($start < $end) {
    $links .= "<a href=\"?month=12\">".date('F', $start)."</a>";
    $start = strtotime($start+'1 month');
}
```

when echoing $links, I just get "August" echoed.

Comment: write date('F Y', $start);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your start date and end date as below:-

```
$start = $month =strtotime("-6 months", strtotime('20015-02-01'));
$end = strtotime("+6 months", strtotime('20015-02-01'));
while($month < $end)
{
     echo date('F Y', $month), PHP_EOL;
     $month = strtotime("+1 month", $month);
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Yes. I have tested it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$now = strtotime(date('d-m-Y'));
$start = strtotime('-6 months');
$end = strtotime('+6 months');

$links = "";
while($start < $end) {
    $links .= "<a href=\"?month=12\">".date('F', $start)."</a>";
    $start = strtotime('+1 month', $start);
}
```

for strtotime the reference point is the second parameter: http://php.net/strtotime